# No type or protocol named UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey

Tags: xcode, react-native, macos

Facing issue while using LinkingIOS with React Native macOS app.

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h> in AppDelegate.m and
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS added in Header Search Path.
```

Error: No type or protocol named 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey'. No known class method for selector 'application:openURL:options:'.

[image]

[image]